# SALESFORCE QUERY ALL - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: salesforce, tibco

When I try to execute SALESFORCE QUERY ALL activity(in server), I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.  From Google NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

But not sure about the exact resolution in Tibco.  Is it an issue with the installation of salesforce plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think this due to a missing JDBC driver for your database vendor.

Check [this](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.1.1/doc/html/GUID-DF12A927-F788-46DC-ABA1-0A1BA797DE2F.html)